# Is it safe to use a signed public address signature as a password

Tags: web3js, security, public-key

So I am building a email/passwordless register and login function on my website and I want my users to use metamask to do so.

So what I thought of doing was using the user public address, signing that address and then using the signed signature as the users password, like so:

```
var walletAddress = 'MyWalletAddress';
var loginKey = walletAddress.substring(2); // remove the 0x
web3.eth.personal.sign(loginKey, walletAddress)
.then((signedSignature) => {
console.log(signedSignature);
// now I can use the signedSignature as the users password
});
```

But is this safe? Or is there a way someone could maybe get the signature by knowing someones public address?

Answer (score 1):

Do not complicate thing for yourself. There is a template for metamask login:

```
const Web3 = require("web3");
const ethEnabled = async () => {
  if (window.ethereum) {
   await window.ethereum.send('eth_requestAccounts');
   window.web3 = new Web3(window.ethereum);
   return true;
  }
  return false;
}
```

Answer (score 0):

Here you go: https://www.toptal.com/ethereum/one-click-login-flows-a-metamask-tutorial

Hope this helps :)